# Initializing hidden input's value attribute as an integer. (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm trying to use a hidden form value as a counter for some Javascript actions. (I.e. something different will happen the second time a user clicks on a spot than the first time.) But code like:

```
<input type="hidden" id="foo" value=0>
```

interprets the initial value as the string '0'. Is there a way to specify I want the value to be an integer, or do I just have to convert the string to an integer later?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't store the counter as a variable in your JavaScript?

Comment: I'm not sure of how to make that work. I have a function called "clicked", and many objects on my page call clicked when they are clicked on. But clicked acts differently based on context, including how many times it has been called already. So that value needs to persist even when the function call is complete.

Comment: All you have to do is declare the variable outside of a function and it will be stored in global memory as long as the page is open. This isn't something you want to do all of the time but for a counter like this its usually my solution. I prefer to wrap these variables in an object, so something like pageVars = {counter = 0;} and then you can just call pageVars.counter += 1; when you need to increment.

Comment: Another idea would be (depending on your requirements) to use `data` attributes. If you're counting something that has some relation to an element (for a very basic example and unrealistic example, counting clicks on a button), you could add a `data-clicks` attribute to the button, and increment *this* with JavaScript. jQuery has a `data()` function which makes interacting with these easy, if you're open to using jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative ideas. I'm definitely an amateur, and I've only been using javascript to write some basic event-handling functions. I've clearly been over-complicating some things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to do it later, I'm afraid. The value will always be a string. Some libraries might intelligently cast it for you but originally yes, it's a string.

Answer (score 2):

True, tags attributes always comes as string. You can do **parseInt(val, 10)** to get the integer.

Answer (score 1):

I did it in that way:

```
<input type="number" id="price_order" name="price" value="" style="display: none">
```